# Firebase RangeError: Invalid string length when retrieving data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm using the Firebase/database Node.js/Admin.

I'm trying to retrieve more than 100K children (and work with it on the client side). 
I got the following error (after a long time loading):

```
/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:161 
function Sf(a,b){a.frames.push(b);if(a.frames.length==a.De){var c=a.frames.join("");a.frames=null;c=eb(c);a.Xf(c)}}h.send=function(a){Rf(this);a=A(a);this.ob+=a.length;Gf(this.Ua,"bytes_sent",a.length);a=pc(a,16384);1<a.length&&Tf(this,String(a.length));for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++)Tf(this,a[b])};h.Qc=function(){this.yb=!0;this.wc&&(clearInterval(this.wc),this.wc=null);this.Ha&&(this.Ha.close(),this.Ha=null)};


RangeError: Invalid string length at Array.join (native)


at Sf (/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:161:76)
at Client.Ha.onmessage (/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:159:289)
```

I'm running this with Node.js with the following code:

```
var databaseRef = defaultApp.database().ref('a_root_node');
var usersRef = databaseRef.child('users')

usersRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
  res.status(200).send(snapshot.val())
})
```

I also try to run it as a Firebase function and increased the memory limit but the error is the same.

Comment: Still seeing this in 2019.  We know we have 240k+ records here.  It's obviously hitting a limit of some kind, but it's not clear where, so we're just guessing at how to workaround / break it up.  In our case, we're just trying to get a numChildren count, but that requires a snapshot of the entire reference to do so.